# injectIntl causing error after adding gatsby-plugin-layout

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin-intl

In order to translate my site I'm injecting `intl` like this in my layout.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import { injectIntl } from "gatsby-plugin-intl";

const Layout = ({intl}) => (
    {intl.formatMessage({id: "history_text"})}
);

export default injectIntl(Layout)
```

But after I added `gatsby-plugin-layout` to my project (based on [this example](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-page-transitions)) I get this error:
`` Error: [React Intl] Could not find required `intl` object. <IntlProvider> needs to exist in the component ancestry. ``

How can I get rid of this error while keeping my translations?

This is the relevant gatsby config part:

```
{
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-intl`,
    options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/locale`,
        languages: [`en`, `de`],
        defaultLanguage: `de`,
        redirect: false,
    },
},
{
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-layout`,
    options: {
        component: require.resolve(`./src/components/layout.js`),
    },
},
```

Comment: how do you provide IntlProvider?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I don't know - I never had a <IntlProvider> tag in my code but the translations still worked.

Comment: So both gatsby-plugin-intl and gatsby-plugin-layout use wrapPageElement API, could you provide gatsby-config to see how they are used

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I never heard of the wrapPageElement API - thx 4 the info, I will check if I can find any useful info on that API. I added the config part to my question.

Comment: You could try to change of the order in which you use the plugins.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri OMG thank u so much!!! That was it! It would be great if you could post the reason why this was the solution in an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gatsby-plugin-layout` and `gatsby-plugin-intl` both make use of `wrapPageElement` API to create a wrapper.

Now the plugins in gatsby are executed from top down and hence you need to define `gatsby-plugin-layout` before `gatsby-plugin-intl` so that the `IntlProvider` provider used by gatsby-plugin-intl wraps the Layout component and it is being able to use the injectIntl HOC

```
{
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-layout`,
    options: {
        component: require.resolve(`./src/components/layout.js`),
    },
},
{
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-intl`,
    options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/locale`,
        languages: [`en`, `de`],
        defaultLanguage: `de`,
        redirect: false,
    },
},
```

Comment: Is there a way to provide more info on this? I tried the same exact setup as you got there, I still get the same error. I tried to pull my layout component to top level and apply it in wrapRootElement function, I got some components in my Layout component with useIntl hooks - basically if I use Layout anywhere above page level, it will throw that error. Gatsby-plugin-layout and gatsby-plugin-intl order didn't seem to make any difference as far as error

Comment: @NikitaTomkevich If you pull Layout over the intlProvider which you do with wrapRootElement you will get the error. If you could provide more details on your setup in a separate question that might be helpful